# compare number to letter

Tags: comparison, letters-and-numbers

Is it possible to compare a number to a letter and make a difference out of it?

What I'm trying to do is:

- Ask the user for a number between `0-10` (choose from a menu)
- Check what that number was, if the number isn't between `0-10` it will
  ask the user for another number

This all works very well until the user inputs a letter (for example 'A').

I'm using `scanf()` to store the value that the user inputs in an integer variable. So if the user `inputs 'A'`, the value 65 gets stored in the variable.

This is causing me a lot of headache, because I want to make a difference between letters and numbers..

Here's my code for checking the input:

```
int checkNumber(int input,int low,int high){
int noPass=0,check=input;

if(check<low){
    noPass=1;
}
if(check>high){
    noPass=1;
}

if(noPass==1){
    while(noPass==1){
        printf("Input number between %d - %d \n",low,high);
        scanf("%d",&check);
        if((check>low)&&(check<high)){
            noPass=0;
        }
    }
}
return check;
}
```

What happens if the user inputs a letter inside the while loop in this function; it starts looping endlessly asking for an input between low and high.

I want to somehow filter out letters, without actually filtering out the `letter's values (65 and above)`.

-Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I continued to wrestle this problem and I came up with this solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//pre: stdlib.h and ctype.h needs to be included, input cannot be initialized to a value within low and high, low cannot be greater than high
//post: returns an integer value that ranges between low and high
int checkNumber(int input,int low,int high){
int noPass=0,check=input;

if(low>high){
    printf("Low is greater than high, abort! \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(isdigit(check)){
    noPass=1;
}
if((check<low)||(check>high)){
    noPass=1;
}
if(noPass==1){
    while(noPass==1){
        printf("Input a number between %d - %d \n",low,high);
        scanf("%d",&check);
        getchar();
        if((check>=low)&&(check<=high)){
            noPass=0;
        }
    }
}
return check;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i=2147483647;

printf("Choose an alternative: \n");
printf("1. Happy Fun time! \n");
printf("2. Sad, sad time! \n");
printf("3. Indifference.. \n");
printf("4. Running out of ideas. \n");
printf("5. Placeholder \n");
printf("6. Hellow World? \n");
printf("0. -Quit- \n");

scanf("%d",&i);
getchar();
i=checkNumber(i,0,6);

if(i==0){
    printf("You chose 0! \n");
}
if(i==1){
    printf("You chose 1! \n");
}
if(i==2){
    printf("You chose 2! \n");
}
if(i==3){
    printf("You chose 3! \n");
}
if(i==4){
    printf("You chose 4! \n");
}
if(i==5){
    printf("You chose 5! \n");
}
if(i==6){
    printf("You chose 6! \n");
}

return 0;
}
```

It works the way I want it to, but it's not perfect. The biggest flaw is that the variable for the value in input (`int i`, in `main()`) cannot be initialized to a value between low and high.
For example: if int i=3; low=0 and high=6, and the user writes a letter: the value of i remains at 3. 3 is sent to checkNumber, and is immediately passed as 3.

I chose to initialize i as 2147483647, which is an unlikely number - but it is still possible.

In conclusion: it works, but it is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

The char automatically become casted into the ASCII code (http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial-anhang-ascii-tabelle.html) . Like u can see, the numbers for the chars are all over the 10 u accept, so the easiest way is to only check if the number is between 0-10 like u said